# CSS multiple div styles

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set purple heading with also underline using this line:

```
<div style="color:purple ; style=text-decoration:underline"><h1>Welcome to the SuperCar Web Site</h1></div>
```

this returning me only purple color, I tried doing it using -[this](http://www.pageresource.com/dhtml/csstut2.htm)- tutorial, I tried doing it by this line:

```
<DIV style="color:red; font-style:italic">I'm some red-hot italic text!</DIV>
```

What is my problem?

Comment: `<div style="color:purple; text-decoration:underline;">` remove second style attribute

Answer (score 2):

You used another style declaration inside a style attribute. If you look again to the red-hot italic code, you can see how to use correctly a style attribute. Your code should be like this:

```
<div style="color: purple; text-decoration: underline;"><h1>Welcome to the SuperCar Web Site</h1></div>
```

PS: You don't need a div element to style your heading. You can use your style declarations in h1 tag as well.

```
<h1 style="color: purple; text-decoration: underline;">Welcome to the SuperCar Web Site</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer in 9 minutes when I will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use style again, before text-decoration
`<div style="color: purple; text-decoration: underline;"><h1>Welcome to the SuperCar Web Site</h1></div>`

Answer (score -1):

you have á wrong syntax in you inline-style

```html
<div style="color:purple; text-decoration:underline"><h1>Welcome to the SuperCar Web Site</h1></div>
```

remove the "inner" style